# Which requires he "be" injected with gamma globulin

Tags: passive-voice, subjunctives, mandative

> He has rare autoimmune disease which requires he ***be injected*** with gamma globulin once every 21 days.

Why do we use "be" in the sentence above? What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

Usually we wouldn't use "the base form of the verb" (**be**) in this position, but would use **is** instead.

Such use of **be** usually expresses a circumstance that is "desired, demanded, recommended, necessary, or similar" (according to Wikipedia). The construction of this type is known as ["mandative subjunctive" (or "jussive subjunctive")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive). It's used with verbs like *insist, suggest, demand, prefer*.

To rephrase,

> He has a rare autoimmune disease, *that's why he needs to be* injected with gamma globulin once every 21 days.

The subjunctive is visible only when we use the third-person singular form of the verb.

Let's remodel the sentence, taking the third-person "nurse" as subject. Note the difference in meaning:

> I *insist* that the nurse **injects** him with gamma globulin once every 21 days.
>   (I give my word that she does this. The "indicative" form, it indicates the reality or the speaker's view of reality.)
>   I *insist* that the nurse **inject** him with gamma globulin once every 21 days.
>   (I want the nurse to do this. The "subjunctive" form, it expresses a desired condition.)

Comment: injects vs inject...?

Comment: @user73963 The second sentence is using the subjunctive: You don't use the _s_ for the third person, and it is _be_ for every person.

Comment: +1 for the last example. It makes perfectly understandable the difference between indicative e subjunctive.

Comment: Thanks, @kiamlaluno! I've lifted that from the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather like to use above form of the sentence.

> He has rare autoimmune disease which requires him to be injected with gamma globulin once every 21 days.